# Error 403: Insufficient Scope returned while using Google People Api for accessing user contacts

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2, google-people-api, yii2-authclient

I am using yii2-authclient to authorize users and import google [contact list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)

Steps I followed:

1. Created Project in Google Console and enabled People API
2. Setup config parameters, controllers, etc using [docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/installation.md). Tested Login and it worked fine. Configured it for contact redirect URI too.
3. For Contacts, created a child class of \yii\authclient\clients\Google and made several tweaks:

   ```
   class Google extends \yii\authclient\clients\Google {
       /**
        * @var array list of attribute names, which should be requested from API to initialize contact list.
        */
       public $attributeNames = [
           'names',
           'emailAddresses',
       ];

       /**
        * Set base URL according for Contacts API
        */
       public function init() {
           parent::init();
           $this->apiBaseUrl = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1';
           if ($this->scope === null) {
               $this->scope = implode(' ', [
                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
               ]);
           }
       }

       /**
        * Call people.connection.list end point
        */
       protected function initUserAttributes() {
           return $this->api('people/me/connections', 'GET', [
               'personFields' => implode(',', $this->attributeNames),
               'pageSize' => 2000,
           ]);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Inside a controller:

   ```
   public function actions() {
       return [
           'import' => [
               'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
               'clientIdGetParamName' => 'authclient',
               'clientCollection' => '[collection_name_from_config]',
               'successCallback' => [$this, 'onImportSuccess'],
           ],
       ];
   }

   public function onImportSuccess($client) {
       ...
       $contacts = $client->getUserAttributes();
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the scope for basic profile information: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`.

Scope list: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#peoplev1

Comment: Didn't work.. Plus, there is no mention of profile scope being required for reading contacts